# Getting default email address on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, email, abaddressbook

I'm trying to get the current user's email (if any) so that I can create a customized "contact us" message.

The code is in C. I've tried with AddressBook.framework but I can't find a way to get the email address.

Anyone knows how to get the email address?
Thank you.

Comment: *Which* email address? One from Mail.app (which account?) One from some other mail client? How about webmail? Or `postfix`? Or one of the ones from the 'Me' card in AddressBook.app?

Comment: the mail set on Mail.app would be a start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using [Address Book C Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/AddressBookC_Collection/_index.html):

`#include <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`

To get all email addresses:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABGetSharedAddressBook();
ABPersonRef user = ABGetMe(addressbook);
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(user, kABEmailProperty);

if(emails)
{
    if(ABMultiValueCount(emails) != 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueCount(emails);i++)
        {
            CFStringRef email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i);

            // Do something with current email string

            CFRelease(email);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(emails);
}
```

Or, to check for the email address marked as the primary one:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABGetSharedAddressBook();
ABPersonRef user = ABGetMe(addressbook);
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(user, kABEmailProperty);

if(emails)
{
    if(ABMultiValueCount(emails) != 0)
    {

        CFStringRef primaryIdentifier = ABMultiValueCopyPrimaryIdentifier(emails);

        for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueCount(emails);i++)
        {
            CFStringRef currentIdentifier = ABMultiValueCopyIdentifierAtIndex(emails, i);

            if(currentIdentifier==primaryIdentifier)
            {
                CFStringRef email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i);

                // Do something with primary email string

                CFRelease(email);
            }

            CFRelease(currentIdentifier);
        }

        CFRelease(primaryIdentifier);
    }

    CFRelease(emails);
}
```

Not all potential errors are handled in the above code, e.g. `ABGetMe()` could return `NULL` if the user hasn’t created an address book entry for herself.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a C girl, how can I convert `CFStringRef` to a simple `char*`?

Comment: and it's crashing on `if(ABMultiValueCount(emails) != 0)`

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/AccessingContents.html

Comment: sorry, I meant it's crashing on `CFRelease(emails);`. The count always comes as 0 (emails is 0)

Comment: Edited and put a null check around the release. Do you have any email addresses in the addressbook?

Comment: Yes, mine and at least 5 others.

Comment: I don't know, still doesn't get them. Any way to use any API to get them directly from Mail.app or its config?

Comment: Great! the `get the primary` returned my email. Thanks for the effort and the code.